# Sencha this.redirectTo() window.history.length on ios

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, browser-history

I am developing a mobile app using sencha extjs. I use route for page view by `this.redirectTo('example',true);` and it works fine. But the problem is that on ios once internet is slow, i open another page redirect to another view but the window.history.length not increased. Anyone face same problem as i do now. Any suggestions for this matter?

> PS: my app requires internet access.

Comment: What do you mean by length not increased ? Can you provide some example

Comment: for working fine case, redirectTo() increase the length by one. it enables to use history.back() to previous page.